# Python in ModelBuilder calculate field tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, field-calculator, python-parser

Code works on ArcMap "Field Calculator..." when I click on attribute and calculate.

But if does not work in ModelBuilder calculate field tool.

Any ideas?

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
  def ifBlock(Country):
    if Country == 'China':
     return "A"
    elif Country == 'Canada':
     return "B"
    elif Country == 'Russia':
     return "C"
```

result=

```
   ifBlock(!Country!)
```

Comment: also, did you check your indentations (this is maybe just due to the layout, but indentations are not correct in your post

Comment: Text field comparison to fill another (text) field. error I get is "ERROR 000539: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<expression>, line 1)
Failed to execute (Calculate Field (3))."

Comment: The code above looks fine. Make sure you've selected "PYTHON" as the expression type.

Comment: I know code is ok, cos its works in field calculator, but not in modelbuilder calculate field tool. I knew there are differences how modelbuilder responds, but this is annoying

Comment: You are not in edit mode right?

Comment: no im not. the code in modelbuilder respondeds differently

Comment: Could you add a screenshot showing your model and the settings of the Calculate Field tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the problem.
i had : behind my result, like this:

result=

```
    ifBlock(!Country!): <--
```

I have **removed** it and now it works fine, thanks all!!!